# Get the most popular github repositories

Tags: javascript, api, github, repository

I need to get the repositories with the most stars. I need to use github API for this.
For example, i can get all repositories that includes 'awesome':

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=awesome
```

But i dont know how to get just the most popular repositories.

Maybe someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this part of the docs.

https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories#search-by-number-of-stars

Under the "Search by number of stars"

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>=1&sort=stars&order=desc
```